# Set minimum version of boost in cmake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I want to define a minimum boost version to be available on the system. I tried the following approach. Unfortunately this did not work, as it tries to compile also with only boost 1.40.0 available on the system.

```
SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
SET(Boost_USE_MULTITHREAD OFF)
SET(BOOST_MIN_VERSION "1.47.0")

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED)

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED)
if (NOT Boost_FOUND)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "Fatal error: Boost (version >= 1.47.0) required.\n")
endif (NOT Boost_FOUND)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

How did I get cmake to control the correct boost version, before compiling?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/cmake@cmake.org/msg14988.html) it seems that FIND_PACKAGE ignores `SET(BOOST_MIN_VERSION "1.47.0")` instead you could use `FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.47.0 REQUIRED)` or slightly nicer `FIND_PACKAGE(Boost ${BOOST_MIN_VERSION} REQUIRED)`

Comment: Thanks FIND_PACKAGE(Boost ${BOOST_MIN_VERSION} REQUIRED) worked.

Comment: @tune2fs This only works for minor versions. If you had boost 2.0 (assuming such a thing existed) this would fail to find it.

Comment: @juanchopanza The idea is that when the MAJOR version is incremented, it won't be compatible with version 1.x. So if you specify 1.47.0 then you don't want it to find a 2.x (since your code is compatible with 1.x, apparently).

Comment: Note what works for boost may not work for other packages. Cmake doesn't define any default version compatibility/comparison criteria, so every package must define their own in <Package>ConfigVersion.cmake. If a package provides <Package>Config.cmake but not <Package>ConfigVersion.cmake, then cmake will assume anything but an exact match is incompatible.