# How to solve the confliction of package_find of CMake?

Tags: c++, c, boost, makefile, cmake

My project uses boost while there are two version of boost(The old one is used for other projects).

In my CMakeList.txt, I use `find_package` to find boost. Unfortunately, it finds an old version of boost, how to solve this case?

My solution is use a var to overwrite `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}`, is there any elegant solution？

Another problem is that I can not use the grammer below:

```
if(ENV{LOCAL_LIBDOUBANM_INCLUDE_DIR})
  blabla
endif()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set minimum version of boost in cmake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855174/set-minimum-version-of-boost-in-cmake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the version you want to the find_package command, i.e. `find_package(Boost 1.50 REQUIRED)`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855174/set-minimum-version-of-boost-in-cmake).